# Cant we use 2s complement or sign bit in biasing the exponent?

Tags: java, c++, c, binary, scientific-notation

Cant we use 2s complement or sign bit in biasing the exponent in 32 bit binary floating point representation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In the IEEE standard, the exponent of a 32-bit float is defined by `2 ^ (127 - exp)`, where `exp` is the value of bits [8:1]. In practice, this is a type of 2's complement. The traditional 2's complement could have been used, but doing it by the standard's way allows for faster float comparisons.